# Adding related column to query results?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a setup in SQLAlchemy ORM (using Flask-SQLAlchemy) with `Book` and `BookSubject` classes, the latter being a many-to-many relationship (there is, of course, a `Subject` class, but it's not relevant to this question). I have a working query to return all books based on the date the *subject* was added to the database (there's a reason for this):

```
 records = Book.query.\
        filter(BookSubject.book_id == Book.id).\
        filter(BookSubject.subject_id.in_([1, 12, 17])).\
        filter(BookSubject.created > '2021-01-01').\
        order_by(db.desc(BookSubject.created)).\
        paginate(page, 50, True)
```

I then pass `records` to a Jinja2 template and do assorted stuff to display it; it works perfectly.

I'd now like to do the obvious thing and actually display the creation date (i.e. `BookSubject.created`, from the order_by clause), but I can't figure out how to add this to the query. Putting in `add_columns((BookSubject.created).label("added"))` isn't the answer; that throws an error when I try to use one of the record objects "'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result object' has no attribute 'id'". The template code that generates this is (roughly):

```
{% for book in records.items %}
  <tr><td><a href="{{ url_for('fullview', id=book.id) }}">{{ book.title }}</a></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This should be obvious; how am I meant to add this to the result?

Comment: `add_columns` is a correct way, the only difference it returns a named tuple (row) instead of an ORM object (Book). please provide the code which produces the last exception.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the post to show both the template code that produces the exception, and also the `paginate` call (from Flask-SQLAlchemy) in the original query that I didn't previously mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `add_columns`

```
Book.query.add_columns((BookSubject.created).label("added"))
```

it will return a named tuple with fields `Book` and `added`, so to access book fields you'd need something like `book.Book.id`

```
{% for book in records.items %}
  <tr><td>
     <a href="{{ url_for('fullview', id=book.Book.id) }}">{{ book.Book.title }} {{ book.added }} </a>
  </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

or iterate by pairs:

```
{% for book, added in records.items %}
  <tr><td>
     <a href="{{ url_for('fullview', id=book.id) }}">{{ book.title }} {{ added }} </a>
  </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want a flat structure (and without `add_columns`), then you can use

```
session.query(
  Book.id,
  Book.title,
  BookSubject.created.label('added')
).filter(BookSubject.book_id == Book.id)...
```

then results will have a named tuple with fields `id`, `title` and `added`, so you can print directly `book.id`:

```
{% for book in records.items %}
  <tr><td>
    <a href="{{ url_for('fullview', id=book.id) }}">{{ book.title }} {{ book.added }} </a>
  </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks. I'm ending up using the last variant, because there are other queries that use the same template and I'd like the structure to remain flat for all of them.